# mysql query concat not working as expected

Tags: mysql, concatenation

here's my data structure:

```
table: items
id   name         category1  category2  category3
--------------------------------------------------
1    apple        1          57         NULL
2    banana       1          41         55
3    orange       1          53         NULL
4    strawberry   1          NULL       NULL
```

desired output:

```
id   name         categories
--------------------------------------------------
1    apple        1,57
2    banana       1,41,55
3    orange       1,53
4    strawberry   1
```

here's my query:

```
SELECT items.*, CONCAT(category, ",", category2, ",", category3) AS categories FROM toom_items
```

something's not working, i'm getting this:

```
id   name         categories
--------------------------------------------------
1    apple        NULL
2    banana       NULL
3    orange       NULL
4    strawberry   NULL
```

any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: I suggest that you use `concat_ws()` because you only need to write the separator once like for example `concat_ws(",", category, category2, category3)` .

Comment: that helped .. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing "1" from first category: Update your query like this:

```
SELECT items.*, CONCAT(category1, ",", category2, ",", category3) AS categories FROM toom_items
```

OR Please use concatenate like this:

```
CONCAT_WS(',', category1, category2, category3);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found two wrong things in your question.

First, your query:

```
SELECT items.*, CONCAT(category, ",", category2, ",", category3) AS categories FROM toom_items
```

You should be referring to the table `items` since in your given example, you do not have a `toom_items` table.

Second, given your query, the result you are getting does not match your query. Since you are selecting `items.*` for the fields then it should be something like:

```
| id   | name       | category1 | category2 | category3 | categories |
+------+------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+------------+
|    1 | apple      |         1 |        57 |      NULL | NULL       |
|    2 | banana     |         1 |        41 |        55 | NULL       |
|    3 | orange     |         1 |        53 |      NULL | NULL       |
|    4 | strawberry |         1 |      NULL |      NULL | NULL       |
```

To answer the question, I have tried your structure and the correct query should be:

```
SELECT id, name, CONCAT_WS(',', category1, category2, category3) as 'categories' FROM items;
```

The result will be:

```
+------+------------+------------+
| id   | name       | categories |
+------+------------+------------+
|    1 | apple      | 1,57       |
|    2 | banana     | 1,41,55    |
|    3 | orange     | 1,53       |
|    4 | strawberry | 1          |
+------+------------+------------+
```

Refer to Screenshot:

[image: CONCAT_WS Query]